# conditional currency sign with angular filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-filter

```
$scope.countries = [{name: 'UNITED KINGDOM', id: 1, sign:"£", 'val':2300987 },{name:    'AUSTRIA', id: 2, sign:"€", 'val':6703482 }
// In HTML
   <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <td class="td-border">{{country.val| currency}}</td>
   </tr>
```

I need angular filter which will take care of currency conditionally as per above object..

Comment: I would add a `{{ country.sign }}` right before `{{ country.val| currency }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Angular Docs**

> Filter definition {{ currency_expression | currency : symbol :
>   fractionSize}}

Simply you could add parameter to filter which would be sign of your currency.

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
    <td class="td-border">{{country.val| currency: country.sign}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to filter the rows based on currency. You can achieve that by simply updating the code to following

```
// In HTML
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries | filter : {sign : currency}">
    <td class="td-border">{{country.val}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want the filter to format your currency you will have to pass the country object or the sign and the val to it, otherwise you can't add the sign with the filter.

```
   .filter('currency', [function() {
    return function(countryObj) {    
            return countryObj.val + countryObj.sign;
        }
    };
    }])
```

Answer (score 0):

The filtering of angular could be bind on the repeater.
Using a separate model to store the current currency is super easy:

```
$scope.currency = "£";
```

Filtering on the repeater will be quite easy then:

```
<tr ng-repeat="country in countries  | filter : { sign : currency || ''}">
                <td class="td-border">{{country.val}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CBgcP/692/